# Error in lav_data "missing observed variables in dataset: " when run CFA

Tags: r, syntax-error, r-lavaan

I am running a CFA with the `lavaan` package in R, but get this error message, saying that some observed variables are missing:

```
Error in lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: Q2 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q12 Q15 Q17 Q18 Q20 Q21 Q25 Q3 Q9 Q10 Q11 Q13 Q14 Q16 Q24 Q26 Q1 Q7 Q8 Q19 Q22 Q23
```

Here is my code:

```
dat <- read.csv(file="C:/.../CFA_R.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")

Factor3.model<-'
 Reward=~ Q2+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q12+Q15+Q17+Q18+Q20+Q21+Q25
 Profession=~ Q3+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q13+Q14+Q16+Q24+Q26
 Mentor=~ Q1+Q7+Q8+Q19+Q22+Q23'

fit<- cfa(model =Factor3.model, data = dat, mimic = "Mplus",
          estimator = "WLSMV", missing = "listwise")
```

I did other descriptive analysis on my data  which means the data was read in successfully.

I don't know what's wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you run summary(dat) with a desirable outcome? Haven't you renamed the dat to data or something similar? It's difficult to tell where's the mistake without reproducible example.

Comment: ï..Q1             Q2      
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.00  
 1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:3.00  
 Median :4.000   Median :4.00  
 Mean   :4.198   Mean   :3.81  
 3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:5.00  
 Max.   :5.000   Max.   :5.00   Yes. I ran summary and didn't see anything abnormal

Comment: Can you edit your question and add `dput(head(dat))`?

Comment: Q1-Q26 is my variable name when I used dput(head(dat)) I got the following outpout structure(list(ï..Q1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Q2 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Q3 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L), Q4 = c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), Q5 = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L), Q6 = c(1L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Q7 = c(1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Q8 = c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L), Q9 = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L), Q10 = c(3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L), Q11 = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Q12 = c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L).....), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
>

Comment: I can run the model on your dput data (after removing missing variables). It only fails at the estimation phase due to the insufficient number of observations. Try to create a simplified example on a new data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because lavaan is looking for `data` but you have defined it as `dat`

This has been fixed in the code block and so the question has inconsistencies.